# Need to re-render every time I change something in the compositor because of full sample

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, antialiasing

Not long ago I have discovered the full sample feature on Blender.
The feature is great and helps a lot. The problem is that whenever I render a frame with Full sample, the image is anti-aliased, but if I change something in the compositor, the image becomes aliased and remain jagged unless I render the entire frame. It is slowing me down because sometimes it takes several hours for a frame to render. Is it just like that, is there any way to avoid re rendering? 
Thank you!

Comment: It's not ideal, but one way to avoid the rerendering is to save the render output (without compositing) as a multilayer EXR file. Then apply the compositing using the EXR file, this avoids re-rendering.

Comment: @MikePan Care to put that in an answer? Comments aren't really the right place for answers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple, however not ideal, is to save the final render to an external file; then loading it up and applying the composite to that.

I would recommend using a multilayer OpenEXR file; these however take up quite a lot of disk space.